# XML list types required for WCF

Tags: xml, wcf, rest

I am sending individual posts of xml data from an android app (java) to a .net 4 WCF web service. The xml is created as follows

```
  xmlBuilder.append("<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?>");
  xmlBuilder.append("<LogDeviceCommunication
  xmlns=\"http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/conxEntities\">");
  xmlBuilder.append("<DeviceID>").append(DeviceID).append("</DeviceID>");
  xmlBuilder.append("<ID>").append(ID).append("</ID>");
  xmlBuilder.append("<Info>").append(Info).append("</Info>");
  xmlBuilder.append("<Line>").append(Line).append("</Line>");
  xmlBuilder.append("<Tab>").append(Tab).append("</Tab>");
  xmlBuilder.append("<Time>").append(new DateTime(Time).toDateTimeISO()).append
  ("</Time>");
  xmlBuilder.append("</LogDeviceCommunication>");
```

WCF method is as follows

```
  [OperationContract]
  [WebInvoke(UriTemplate = "AddDeviceCommunicationLog", RequestFormat = 
  WebMessageFormat.Xml, BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Bare, Method = "POST")]
  string AddDeviceCommunicationLog(LogDeviceCommunication deviceCommunicationEntry);
```

I want to change to sending a List of LogDeviceCommunication to speed things up but not sure what to use as a parent element i.e

```
<parent element>
  <logdevicecommunication>...</logdevicecommunication>
  <logdevicecommunication>...</logdevicecommunication>
  <logdevicecommunication>...</logdevicecommunication>
</parent element>
```

Calls to WCF normally return a List as ArrayOf.... but naturally this type does not exist when posting. 
Do I need to create a messagecontract or similar?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need a collection Data Contract type, e.g.:

```
[CollectionDataContract(Name="WhateverYouWantToCallTheRootElement")]
public class LogDeviceCommunications: Collection<LogDeviceCommunication>  {}
```

Then change your operaton method to take an argument of this new type.